Mongodb, Mongoose, buffering timed out after 10000ms for only 1 document
it was because of User. I just moved it inside of the code, and it worked, thanks for your help
I am working on my project to create just a small mini project for messaging.I am more of a frontend, so backend is a little scratch, I will learn about it more soon. The problem is I would like to get data from mongodb with mongoose on my backend and I am getting an error:
MongooseError: Operation users.find() buffering timed out after 10000ms
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../models/user");
const cors = require("cors");
const http = require("http");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: ["http://localhost:5173"],
  },
});
const db =
  "link";

async function toMongoose() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(db);
    console.log("Connected");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

toMongoose();

app.get("/get-users", async (req, res) => {
  const users = await User.find();
  res.json(users);
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(socket.id);
  socket.on("sending-message", (message) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive-message", message);
  });
});
server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on http://localhost:3000`);
});

what could be the problem? As far as I know, it is connected, because it console.logs the "Connected"
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
module.exports = User;

could it be because of model?

try this and let me know const User = require("./models/user"), just remove a single dot.

Does this answer your question? How to solve Mongoose v5.11.0 model.find() error: Operation `products.find()` buffering timed out after 10000ms"

@Subha after removing one dote it shows me
'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

@ray the problem, of that person was that, he did not include async await, while I did

it was because of User. I just moved it inside of the code, and it worked, thanks for your help

@Batyrlan If you believe the issue would be relevant for other users, you can post your solution on the duplicate post suggested above.
